# Why do we cast sockaddr_in to sockaddr when calling bind()?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

The [bind()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind) function accepts a pointer to a `sockaddr`, but in all examples I've seen, a `sockaddr_in` structure is used instead, and is cast to `sockaddr`:

```
struct sockaddr_in name;
...;
if (bind (sock, (struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof (name)) < 0) {
  ...;
}
```

I can't wrap my head around why is a `sockaddr_in` struct used. Why not just prepare and pass a `sockaddr`?

Is it just convention?

Comment: NB. `sockaddr_in6` also exists, and anyone writing new code would be wise to include it…

Comment: You have omitted one very important part in your code: `name.sa_family = AF_INET` for `struct sockaddr_in`! Consider `struct sockaddr` to be a union of all other sockaddr types. The only thing in common is that they have a first member `sa_family_t sa_family` which must correspond to the actual structure type.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

No, it's not just convention.

`sockaddr` is a generic descriptor for any kind of socket operation, whereas `sockaddr_in` is a struct specific to IP-based communication (IIRC, "in" stands for "InterNet"). As far as I know, this is a kind of "polymorphism" : the `bind()` function pretends to take a `struct sockaddr *`, but in fact, it will assume that the appropriate type of structure is passed in; i. e. one that corresponds to the type of socket you give it as the first argument.

Comment: Just to add: `sockaddr_in6` is for IPv6 addresses, `sockaddr_un` for Unix domain sockets, ...

Comment: @MartinR I was also thinking about Bluetooth (if I'm not mistaken, Linux does RFCOMM over sockets), etc.

Comment: There are a lot of socket types that I do not know ... It might be worth to mention `struct sockaddr_storage`, which is also "generic" in some sense and is large enough to hold any type of socket address.

Comment: To put it in layman's terms, if a function accepts `Cat` then we can't use it with `Dog`, but if the function accepts `Animal`, then we can put any `Animal` into the function, such as `Cat`, `Dog`, `Tiger`, etc. (Well, yeah C is not OOP language but you get the point :)

Answer (score 27):

I don't know if its very much relevant for this question, but I would like to provide some extra info which may make the typecaste more understandable as many people who haven't spent much time with `C` get confused seeing such a typecaste.

I use `macOS`, so I am taking examples based on header files from my system.

`struct sockaddr` is defined as follows:

```
struct sockaddr {
    __uint8_t       sa_len;         /* total length */
    sa_family_t     sa_family;      /* [XSI] address family */
    char            sa_data[14];    /* [XSI] addr value (actually larger) */
};
```

`struct sockaddr_in` is defined as follows:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    __uint8_t       sin_len;
    sa_family_t     sin_family;
    in_port_t       sin_port;
    struct  in_addr sin_addr;
    char            sin_zero[8];
};
```

Starting from the very basics, a pointer just contains an address. So `struct sockaddr *` and `struct sockaddr_in *` are pretty much the same. They both just store an address. Only relevant difference is how compiler treats their objects.

So when you say `(struct sockaddr *) &name`, you are just tricking the compiler and telling it that this address points to a `struct sockaddr` type.

---

So let's say the pointer is pointing to a location `1000`. If the `struct sockaddr *` stores this address, it will consider memory from `1000` to `sizeof(struct sockaddr)` possessing the members as per the structure definition. If `struct sockaddr_in *` stores the same address it will consider memory from `1000` to `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)`.

---

When you typecasted that pointer, it will consider the same sequence of bytes upto `sizeof(struct sockaddr)`.

```
struct sockaddr *a = &name; // consider &name = 1000
```

Now if I access `a->sa_len`, the compiler would access from location `1000` to `sizeof(__uint8_t)` which is same bytes size as in case of `sockaddr_in`. So this should access the same sequence of bytes.

Same pattern is for `sa_family`.

After that there is a 14 byte character array in `struct sockaddr` which stores data from `in_port_t sin_port` (`typedef`'d 16 bit unsigned integer = 2 bytes ) , `struct  in_addr sin_addr` (simply a 32 bit ipv4 address = 4 bytes) and `char sin_zero[8]`(8 bytes). These 3 add up to make 14 bytes.

Now these three are stored in this 14 bytes character array and we can access any of these three by accessing appropriate indices and typecasting them again.

user529758's answer already explains the reason to do this.

Comment: What troubles me is I can understand either a `void*` + size OR a "weak" type that that you cast your specific types with the call assuming a common size but I have a hard time wrapping my head around both...

Comment: The key part: _"After that there is a 14 byte character array in `struct sockaddr` ... These 3 add up to make 14 bytes. ... Now these three are stored in this 14 bytes character array ..."_

Answer (score 6):

This is because bind can bind other types of sockets than IP sockets, for instance Unix domain sockets, which have sockaddr_un as their type. The address for an AF_INET socket has the host and port as their address, whereas an AF_UNIX socket has a filesystem path.