# socket programming - meaning of the parameter in connect()

Tags: c, sockets

I just started to learn socket programming and found this unusual argument in the `connect()` function.

```
(struct sockaddr *)&server
```

snippet of socket() function:

```
if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    puts("connect error");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we cast sockaddr\_in to sockaddr when calling bind()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099041/why-do-we-cast-sockaddr-in-to-sockaddr-when-calling-bind)

Comment: Why did you mention `socket()` three times when your question is about `connect()`?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you are confused by why a pointer to `server`, which I assume is of type `sockaddr_in` is not passed to the function and instead it is cast to a pointer to `struct sockaddr`, then here is your answer:

The `struct sockaddr_in` is just a wrapper structure for `struct sockaddr`:

```
struct sockaddr {
    unsigned short sa_family;
    char           sa_data[14];
};
```

The port number and the ip address are held together here. They are held together in `sa_data[14]`-  the first `2 bytes` holding the port number, and the next `4 bytes` holding the ip address. The remaining `8 bytes` are unused. These are the `8 bytes` you clear to zeroes via `sin_zero[8]` when you use `sockaddr_in`.

Functions like `connect()` does not know of any type `struct sockaddr_in`, they only know of `struct sockaddr`.

Answer (score 1):

The `server` is the protocol address of the host you're connecting to. If it's IPv4 socket, you should be using `struct sockaddr_in*` cast into `struct sockaddr*`, if it's IPv6 socket, you should be using `struct sockaddr_in6*` cast into `struct sockaddr*`.

Comment: no I am just confused with the syntax and casting and such... please help me with that...

Comment: Well, it expects you to give a pointer, hence `&server` and not `server`. And because it's used for all protocols that have different `sockaddr_foo` structures you cast it into `struct sockaddr*`, a common struct for all protocols. Hence `(struct sockaddr*)&server`.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099041/why-do-we-cast-sockaddr-in-to-sockaddr-when-calling-bind

Answer (score 1):

The `sockaddr` structure is used to store an Internet Protocol (IP) address for a machine participating in a Windows Sockets communication. the `connect()` function is used at the client side to connect with the server. So the second argument is basically filled with the server IP and port information, so that client can connect with the server identified by IP and Port

Comment: no I am just confused with the syntax and casting and such... please help me with that