# Networking, sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, networking

Can someone explain to me the purpose of this line of code, especially the
`(struct sockaddr *)&host_addr` parameter?

```
bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&host_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

Comment: `host_addr` contains the local address and port of the socket. For a server, this is the port that it listens for incoming connections on.

Comment: Are you asking why it uses the `(struct sockaddr *)` cast?

Comment: what about the (struct sockaddr *) part?

Comment: It binds the socket to the address specified in the host address.  The host address structures are plain weird — they predate `void *`, but nowadays, that's what would be used if the interface was (re)designed from scratch.  So, instead of `void *`, the `struct sockaddr *` type is used, but the values passed are different types (an IPv4 address uses less space than an IPv6 one, and both are different from a 'Unix-domain' socket address, aka filename), as a uniform pointer type.  Hence the cast.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099041/why-do-we-cast-sockaddr-in-to-sockaddr-when-calling-bind

Comment: yes i dont understand that part