# why If the cast (struct sockaddr *) is omitted, C compiler generates a warning “incompatible pointer type”

Tags: c, sockets

I am a newbie to socket programming. I want to know why we need to do casting like this `(struct sockaddr *) &servAddrbind` when we bind a socket:

```
bind (sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
```

Why can't we do binding without such cast?

Comment: Take a look at the answers to ["Why do we cast sockaddr\_in to sockaddr when calling bind()?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099041/why-do-we-cast-sockaddr-in-to-sockaddr-when-calling-bind) In short, `bind` can work with multiple types of socket address, but a function can't accept more than one type for the same argument, so you have to cast your socket address to the generic `sockaddr` to pass it in.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply i just want why we need to casting in generic socket address structure rather than doing  like this "int bind (socket, localaddr, addrlen)" which we do in ANSI C function

Comment: It's because the second argument of `bind` must be a pointer to a `struct sockaddr`, but you are actually passing in a pointer to a `struct sockaddr_in` or some other type of address struct.