# why do we use * and & when trying to connect to a server with sockets in c

Tags: c, sockets, networking

```
connect(socket_desc , (struct sock_address *)&server , sizeof(server)
```

why do we use * and & when trying to connect to a server or bind a server its like making a pointer or something but i believe that * doesn't make a pointer when combined with so why putting them both ?
thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
(struct sock_address *)&server
```

simply states: use the address of `server`, cast to a "pointer to sock_address structure".

You need to give the address because the function wants to *change* the things in that structure. And the cast is simply so it's the correct type.

It's *not* the same as:

```
int num = 42;
int num2 = *(&num); // num would be better.
```

which *would* be the two cancelling each other out.

While `*ptr` *dereferences* `ptr` to give you the underlying value, `(type *)ptr` instead treats `ptr` as if it was a pointer to `type` - there is no dereferencing in the latter case.

Comment: so i cant do struct sock_address server ?

Comment: @soldiercaptain: in the UNIX world, you tend to have specific address types (like `sockaddr_in` for IP)  but `connect` is meant to handle *all* types. The various `sockaddr_XX` types are cast to `sockaddr` so that `connect` gets a common type but `connect` itself is able to distinguish what type it is and act appropriately. Sort of a poor man's polymorphism :-) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099041/why-do-we-cast-sockaddr-in-to-sockaddr-when-calling-bind for more detail.